# htaccess redirect and nofollow

Tags: .htaccess, ranking

Im redirecting a someurl to www.example.com using htaccess 301 redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

Also in the htaccess im writing a rule to not index the www.example.com .
What i need is all the results under www.example.com should appear in google except the root(www.example.com)

Below is the code for noindex

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <IF "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /^$/">
        Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
    </IF>
</IfModule>
```

Is it something that is possible?